# Is it possible to have different phpcs configuration values for different files?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, phpcs

I'm using [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) with [PHPCompatibility](https://github.com/PHPCompatibility/PHPCompatibility) and I'd like to have different configuration values for different files.

For some files I want the following configuration:

```
<config name="testVersion" value="5.5-"/>
```

And for other files:

```
<config name="testVersion" value="5.2-"/>
```

I'd like to do this from my `phpcs.xml` file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently not possible. The best you can do is run `phpcs` twice with different rulesets or with different command-line arguments.